# How to solve Timeout FeignClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, netflix-feign

My application is getting below error when consuming a service that performs queries in SQL Server using `FeignClient`.

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-14" feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8876/processoData/search/buscaProcessoPorCliente?cliente=ELEKTRO+-+TRABALHISTA&estado=SP

My Consumer Service:

```
@FeignClient(url="http://127.0.0.1:8876")
public interface ProcessoConsumer {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/processoData/search/buscaProcessoPorCliente?cliente={cliente}&estado={estado}")
public PagedResources<ProcessoDTO> buscaProcessoClienteEstado(@PathVariable("cliente") String cliente, @PathVariable("estado") String estado);

}
```

My YML:

```
server:
  port: 8874

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

eureka:
  client:
  serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: ${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8764}/eureka/
  instance: 
    preferIpAddress: true

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

spring:
  application:
    name: MyApplication
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
      port: 27017
      uri: mongodb://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/recortesExtrator
      repositories.enabled: true
    solr:
      host: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8983/solr
      repositories.enabled: true
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Renan, after which time you get a timeout error and how long does a call to the backend usually take?

Comment: Why your Feign client says port 8876 but your YML configuration says port 8874?

Answer (score 54):

Add the following properties into `application.properties` file, in milliseconds.

```
feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=160000000
feign.client.config.default.readTimeout=160000000
```

Comment: Having tried all sort of black magic with properties consisting of Hystrix, ribbon and what not, this is the cleanest (and working) solution that I have encountered.

Comment: The catch is that both need to be set for either of them to take effect. ‍♂️ Here's the relevant [source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/21a2a59461f95fc1c78bd26a6f55187cc576c617/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClientFactoryBean.java#L171)

Comment: I experimented the same issue, fixing the timeout only after setting both properties.
An additional tip, you can configure different timeouts to different APIs replacing the _default_ word for the API feignName as described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)

Answer (score 16):

I'm using `Feign.builder()` to instantiate my Feign clients.

In order to set `connectTimeout` and `readTimeout`, I use the following :

```
Feign.builder()
     ...
     .options(new Request.Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout))
     .target(MyApiInterface.class, url);
```

Using this I can configure different timeout for different APIs.

Comment: this .options is now deprecated, better use the new one .options(new Request.Options(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_IN_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS,CONNECTION_TIME_OUT_IN_SEC, TimeUnit.Seconds, true)).
The last param is for followRedirects.

You can give any timeout value based on the unit provided.

Answer (score 9):

just ran into this issue as well. As suggested by @spencergibb here is the workaround I'm using. See the [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/696)

Add these in the application.properties.

```
# Disable Hystrix timeout globally (for all services)
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Add this in the Java configuration class.

```
import feign.Request;

@Configuration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = { ServiceFeignClient.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ServiceFeignClient.class })
public class FeignConfig {

    /**
     * Method to create a bean to increase the timeout value, 
     * It is used to overcome the Retryable exception while invoking the feign client.
     * @param env,
     *            An {@link ConfigurableEnvironment}
     * @return A {@link Request}
     */
    @Bean
    public static Request.Options requestOptions(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        int ribbonReadTimeout = env.getProperty("ribbon.ReadTimeout", int.class, 70000);
        int ribbonConnectionTimeout = env.getProperty("ribbon.ConnectTimeout", int.class, 60000);

        return new Request.Options(ribbonConnectionTimeout, ribbonReadTimeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Hystrix, and all other suggestions to use ribbon.Read and Connect Timeout didn't work for me. But adding this bean solved it.

Answer (score 3):

For those who use spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:

spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.readTimeout=5000
spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=5000

Answer (score 2):

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=6000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=60000
```

make sure ribbon's timeout is bigger than hystrix

Comment: That should be exactly vice versa:
"When using Hystrix commands that wrap Ribbon clients you want to make sure your Hystrix timeout is configured to be longer than the configured Ribbon timeout, including any potential retries that might be made. For example, if your Ribbon connection timeout is one second and the Ribbon client might retry the request three times, than your Hystrix timeout should be slightly more than three seconds."
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_hystrix_timeouts_and_ribbon_clients

Comment: Updated link to @AlexanderPalamarchuk comment's source:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__hystrix_timeouts_and_ribbon_clients.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'Options' argument to you methods and control timeouts dynamically.

```
@FeignClient(url="http://127.0.0.1:8876")
public interface ProcessoConsumer {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/processoData/search/buscaProcessoPorCliente?cliente={cliente}&estado={estado}")
    PagedResources<ProcessoDTO> buscaProcessoClienteEstado(@PathVariable("cliente") String cliente, @PathVariable("estado") String estado,
                                                                  Request.Options options);
}
```

Use like next:

```
processoConsumer.buscaProcessoClienteEstado(..., new Request.Options(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below properties to the application.properties file

value 5000 is in milliseconds

```
feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout: 5000
feign.client.config.default.readTimeout: 5000
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the most voted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602627/spring-cloud-feign-hytrix-first-call-timeout). It did the trick for me. I also did a bit of research and I've found the properties documentation here:

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#intro

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer.

Answer (score -3):

eureka:
  client:
    eureka-server-read-timeout-seconds: 30

Answer (score -4):

Add these in the application.properties

> feign.hystrix.enabled=false
>   hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000