# How to make seperate different read timeout for APIs in feign client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using feign client in my spring boot application and I want to configure separate timeouts for different calls for example if I have update and create calls and I want to set read time out for update = 3000 and for create =12000, how can I do that?

```java
@FeignClient(name = "product-service")
public interface ProductClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/product/create")
    public ProductCreation productCreationExternalRequest(@RequestBody ProductCreationRequest productCreationRequest);
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/product/update")
    public ProductCreation productUpdateExternalRequest(@RequestBody ProductCreationRequest productCreationRequest );
    
}
```

My service class is :

```java
    public class  MyService {
    .
    .
    productCreationResponse = productClient.productCreationExternalRequest(productCreationRequest);
    ..
    productupdateResponse = productClient.productUpdateExternalRequest(productCreationRequest);
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Timeout FeignClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080283/how-to-solve-timeout-feignclient)

Comment: Add a configuration class  definning two beans of '@Bean
    public Request.Options options() {
        return new Request.Options(connectTimeOutMillis, readTimeOutMillis);
    }'

Comment: @hilmi can you explain ,it,,,means how i can i bring it in my case

Comment: There is on way : 1- separate productCreationExternalRequest & productUpdateExternalRequest in separated two feign clients(each feign client use its own configuration '@FeignClient(value = "product-service", configuration = UpdateFeignConfig.class, fallbackFactory = UpdatetFallbackFactory.class, url = "")'class that define the read time out ) that reference two services that its not the standard so i think that your need is not applicable for this purpose ..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by sending options parameter as argument of you feign methods:

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service")
public interface ProductClient {
    @PostMapping(value = "/product/create")
    ProductCreation productCreationExternalRequest(ProductCreationRequest productCreationRequest, Request.Options options);

    @PostMapping(value = "/product/update")
    ProductCreation productUpdateExternalRequest(ProductCreationRequest productCreationRequest, Request.Options options);
}
```

And then use your methods like next:

```
productClient.productCreationExternalRequest(new ProductCreationRequest(), new Request.Options(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
           1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true));
productClient.productUpdateExternalRequest(new ProductCreationRequest(), new Request.Options(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
           100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true));
```